# Arguments to ninject modules

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I need to provide some global scope to a ninject module, and figure that it would be best to inject this in via a module.

I'm currently scanning assemblies for modules, and as such, can't determine how to provide these arguments (cleanly).

I have a console app, and I want to choose the implementation of a type based on the arguments to the application.

The issue is that those types have a dependency on the specific deserialisation of those arguments, which is determined at lookup time.

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
public class Module : MyNinjectModule<Module>
{
    private enum FictionalEnum
    {
        FirstType,
        SecondType
    }

    private string[] _args;

    private FictionalEnum Type
    {
        get
        {
            return IsFirstType(_args)
                       ? FictionalEnum.FirstType
                       : FictionalEnum.SecondType;
        }
    }

    public Module(string[] rawArgs)
    {
        _args = rawArgs;
    }

    protected override void  LoadCustomBindings()
    {
        Bind<IBaseType>().To<FirstImpl>()
            .When(req => this.Type == FictionalEnum.FirstType);

        Bind<IBaseType>().To<SecondImpl>()
            .When(req => this.Type == FictionalEnum.SecondType);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion this logic does not belong into a module. I would either inject all the instances and then decide in the application which of the instances to take or inject a factory and let the factory create the correct type depending on the argument.